# Customize UIStatusBar in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to customize the `UIStatusBar` class?

Comment: </strike>I don't write iPhone apps</strike>, but here is an article about it: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UIStatusBar.html It took me 2 seconds to Google it.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this customizing the statusbar. This is more like choosing which of the three default styles you want.

Answer (score 4):

For an example what you can do with (or around) the status bar, look at this Github project: https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay

I have used it in a project of mine, and it goes through app review just fine.

Comment: One note about that.  Do not partially-obscure the built-in status bar.  That will merit a rejection.  If you cover it up fully that is generally OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can not customize the UIStatusBar.
What you **can** do, is to put another UIView on top (with any customizations you want).

For example, something like:

```
MyView * myview = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myview];
```