# Display network connection status in UIStatusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistatusbar

I have an app which completely depends on connection to the internet. At the moment, I use an UIAlertView to notify the user whether the device is connected to the Internet or not. I feel this is too ugly and intrusive. I would like to set up a notification system where such a status message is shown in the `UIStatusBar` like in some apps such as the new MailBox app from DropBox. Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: There is a github project which allows for status bar customizations. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13963067/35499)

Comment: Hmm. It works, but it provides few customisation options and I see there are issues with apps being rejected by apple when this is used. Any other suggestions you have?

Comment: You can give https://github.com/mwielbut/StatusBarMessageExample a look. Not exactly what you want, but it shows a secondary status bar right below the system status bar.